# intellij-idea does not respect /*@formatter:off*/ when not defined on line by itself

Tags: intellij-idea, formatter

When given the following code (single line):

```
/*@formatter:off*/ try{ /*do stuff*/ }catch(Exception e){ /*catch me*/ } /*@formatter:on*/
```

After reformatting code Intellij will reformat it to (two lines):

```
/*@formatter:off*/
try { /*do stuff*/ }catch (Exception e) { /*catch me*/ } /*@formatter:on*/
```

How do I prevent Intellij from adding a new line after `/*@formatter:off*/`?

This is what my code style formatter option looks like:

[File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOKR8.png)

Comment: File a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.